# How to pass selected item to parent view model

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, viewmodel

I have the view model structure as follow,

[ViewModel Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWqTF.png)

Please click the above link for structure

Interfaces are,

```
TopViewModel: ITopVM
ITopVM
{            
IItemVM  SelectedItem {get;set;}
}
```

All children of topviewmodel implements IItemViewModel

```
IItemViewModel
{
IItemVM  SelectedItem {get;set;}
Event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs<IItemVM>> {get;}
ObservableCollection<IItemVM> Children {get;}   
}
```

Question is how can I pass the newly selected item (**Child_2**) from **Group_A_2** to top view model when the collection is changed and set the top view model selected item as **Child_2**?

Conditions are,

- Category view model should know only about Group view model (i.e. ,
  child_2 should not be set as category view model’s selected item).
- every parent view model should know only about its child view model.

Comment: Conditions seem arbitrary and serve no purpose except to make your task more difficult.

Comment: I feel it brings better encapsulation in design